# Run `\watch` command in DataGrip

Tags: datagrip

How can I run psql `\watch` command in DataGrip?
source https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/app-psql.html

Answer (score 1):

at the moment such commands are not supported in IDE, please follow and vote for [this request on our tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-6155).